# how to take screenshot of dragged and dropped elements using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating an app in which a user drags an image from one div and drops it into a canvas. how to take a screenshot of the canvas along with those images dropped into that canvas.

```
<canvas class="can" > </canvas>
<div class="pictures">
   <img src="abc.jpg" />   //before dragging
   <img src="xyz.jpg" style="top: -150px" />   //after dragging and dropping into the canvas
</div>
```

js

```
 function call(top,this1){
// alert("hello");

if(top==0){
    var clone= this1.clone();
    clone.css("top","0");
    clone.draggable({addClasses: true ,
        revert: "invalid",
        drag:function(){
            var position = $(this).position();
            var top=position.top;
            call(top,$(this));
        }
    });
    this1.parent().prepend(clone);
    this1.css("position","absolute");
```

}
}

```
$("img").draggable({
    addClasses: true ,
    revert: "invalid",
    drag: function(){
        var position = $(this).position();
        var top=position.top;
        call(top,$(this));
     }
   }

   );

$(".canvas").droppable({
    out: function(e,ui){
        $(ui.draggable).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code I assume you are using jQueryUI.

**1** `$(".canvas")` does not exist. Since your `canvas` has a classname `can`, you should use `$("canvas")` or `$(".can")`.

**2** drag/drop only changes the element's visual behavior, not its DOM structure. If you want to do so, you should define a drop method, it is fired when you drop something on it:

```
$("canvas").droppable({
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        // anything here, e.g. manipulate the DOM
        // regarding this answer, you could fire canvas drawImage here
    },
    out: function(e,ui){
        $(ui.draggable).remove();
        // regarding this answer, you may need to clear the canvas and repaint, to "visually" remove the picture
    }
});
```

**3** Child nodes of a canvas is ONLY displayed when the browser doesn't support canvas, it is for fallback. So it doesn't really make sense to append an image to canvas.

Ok, now we should be clear that you forget to inspect DOM structure in devtool, just focus on drawing canvas (I'm using native JS here).

```
var img = document.querySelector("img"); // the image you are dragging
var cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

// this will draw the image to canvas at its coordination (10, 10)
ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
```

You already know the coordination information when you're dragging it, so you can draw it to exactly the same position where you drop on the canvas.

**Tips**: you can even crop part of the image, scale it then draw to canvas. See this link for a full list of its parameters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage

Moreover, if you want to save canvas content as binary image file, you can use `cvs.toDataURL` to get base64 string of the image.

```
var url = cvs.toDataURL('image/png');
```

Then you can do whatever you want, for example, generate a button that user can click and save the image to his hard disk.

```
var save = document.createElement('a');
save.setAttribute('download', 'any_name.png');
save.setAttribute('href', url);
document.appendChild(save);
```

Comment: Multiple images can be dropped on the canvas. Also placing a clone of those images in the original place.

So how shall i do it for multiple images

Comment: So, several things to do: **1** You deal with drag/drop event to collect information (which picture, dropping coordination, etc). **2** draw image to canvas, which is answered. **3** export canvas content (might be necessary although you don't ask, answered as well). Is that correct?

Comment: yes but when i drag and drop those images, they are not exactly placed in canvas. when i check the code in developers tool, those images are still in '.pictures' and not in 'canvas'. Just the top parameter is changed as i have mentioned in the example

Comment: Can you post your JS part in the original question?